# Fill Excel cells based on ComboBox value

Tags: excel, combobox

I created a combobox in Excel with values. I want fill any cells range based on combobox value. For example, if combobox value is "A", I would like to give specific values to cells range A1:A6.

How can I do it... Help

Answer (score 0):

You should use a formula in `A1:A6` to calculate their values based on the output from your combobox. There are several options for this. Your combobox will change the value of its linked cell based on the index of item selected. If the first item is selected, the linked cell will have value `1`, if second - `2` and so on. For example, if your combobox is linked to cell `B1`:

1) You can use [`CHOOSE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc) to select the value you need by using the index from linked cell:

```
=CHOOSE($B$1,"Value 1","Value 2","Value 3"...)
```

2) You can use nested `IF()` formulas to determine which value to display:

```
=IF($B$1=1,"Value A",IF($B$1=2,"Value B",IF($B$1=3,"Value C","Value D")))
```

3) You can use [`VLOOKUP()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) to pick a value from a certain list of key-value pairs (I would recommend placing it on a different worksheet, say `Sheet2!$A:$B`):

```
=VLOOKUP($B$1,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```